# Of a minima problem in optics

Tags: calculus, geometry, maxima-minima

I have trodding through a calculus textbook, more specifically — through a chapter on the methods of obtaining the extrema of functions using derivatives, including certain problems in optics (Fermat’s principle) as examples of their usage. To this chapter there is a problem set, and one of the problems is as follows:

*A prism deflects a beam of light travelling in a plane perpendicular to the edge of the prism. What must the relative position of prism and beam be for the deflection to be a minimum.*

To be fair, it has been more than a year since I last took an optics class; furthermore, I highly doubt the fact that we covered the notion of „deflection” of a beam of light passing through a refracting medium (a very basic high-school course in optics). I do not really need any hints or, God forbid, solutions to this problem. I simply want to be clear on the question. Do we assume that the prism is of some concrete shape? What exactly is meant by the „deflection” of the beam? How should I even picture this problem?

This is important, and though I have already said this, but I think it necessary to reiterate: **I do not need solutions or hints, but a mere clarification of the formulation of the problem.**

I shall be incredibly grateful to those who provide assistance. Thank you!

Comment: Imagine an incident beam on a wedge (a "V"). After two refractions, you have an outgoing beam, with a different direction with respect to the incident beam.
What is the incident angle that minimizes the angle between incident and outgoing directions?
I may do a drawing by the end of the day if the wording is not clear.

Comment: The solution might be a function of the wedge angle.

Comment: 1. Prism has two plane faces, intersecting at the edge of the prism. These two faces are refracting the light, other geometry of prism has no importance for the problem. 2. Deflection is angle between incident and outgoing beam. 3. As light travels in plane perpendicular to the edge of the prism, you can draw picture in cross-section of prism by this plane.

Comment: I believe I have got the hang of it, finally. Thank you all!

Comment: This is a classical problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_deviation